# getting 400 error for jsonarray using resttemplate

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am using resttemplate and post the json array using an object but I am getting the 400 (HTTP message not readable).
Here is my code:

The json data is:
    [{"timestamp":1521549412000, "sysValue": 80, "meanValue": 120}]

```
BaseData baseData  = new BaseData();
baseData.setSysValue(80);
baseData.setMeanValue(120);
baseData.setTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

HttpEntity<BaseData> entity = new HttpEntity<BaseData>(baseData, headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = RestTemplate.getRestTemplate();

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl,HttpMethod.POST,entity,String.class);
```

I am getting 400 error , ("errorType":"invalid_input","errorMessage":"HTTP message not readable")
I am not sure what is missing. can somebody help me

Answer (score 0):

The request body that will be sent for the code snippet you pasted will be 
`{"timestamp":1521549412000, "sysValue": 80, "meanValue": 120}` and not `[{"timestamp":1521549412000, "sysValue": 80, "meanValue": 120}]`.

This is why you could be getting 400 error.

Make the following change to post a json array instead of a json object.

```
List<BaseData> requestBody = new ArrayList<>();
requestBody.add(baseData);
HttpEntity<BaseData> entity = new HttpEntity<BaseData>(requestBody, headers);
```